# Xamarin: Button being overlayed by frame

Tags: xaml, xamarin

Trying to make a button that will overlay on top of a grid in xaml

```
<Frame Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="15" Padding="15">
   <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="**************3454" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
       <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Verify" HorizontalOptions="End" TextColor="#A1A0E1" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
   </Grid>
</Frame>
<Button Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Red" Command="{Binding VerifyCommand}"/>
```

However, it ends up looking like this:
[underlayed button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlH6K.png)

Any thoughts on how to make the button go on top?

Answer (score 0):

Place everything inside the Grid and use a Grid.ColumnSpan of 2 on your Frame and Button and of course set your Button's background to `Transparent`:

```
   <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <Frame Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="15" Padding="15" BorderColor="White"/>
       <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="**************3454" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
       <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Verify" HorizontalOptions="End" TextColor="#A1A0E1" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
       <Button Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Command="{Binding VerifyCommand}"/>
   </Grid>
```